# How to trigger event for incoming BLE connection/pairing request in UWP application?

Tags: windows, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi-direct, c++-winrt

May be this question is similar to the question asked [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348078/uwp-how-to-check-incoming-requests-from-ble-device). I did not get any clue from the answer, so I am expecting some more suggestions/answers and asking a question.

I have implemented a console application which uses UWP C++/Winrt APIs to advertise and scan for BLE devices. Advertisement is being done using GATT service provider with custom UUID and Scanning is performed with help of Device Watcher. Pairing mechanism is implemented with help of Custom Pairing(PairAsync()) with few device pairing kinds(such as Display Pin, Provide Pin etc...).

Now, I am running the same application on 2 different laptops. From one Laptop, I initiated connection request and expecting custom UI(which is implemented by me) to popup at other laptop. But it did not happen, only at initiator end Custom UI(which is implemented by me) popped up to Provide Pin and other end default Windows UI popped to Display Pin . From this, I understood that incoming pairing/connection request is being handled by Windows stack. I have searched a lot but could not find the way to get event in UWP application.

I found that in Wi-Fi direct, there is dedicated class available for [WiFiDirectConnectionListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifidirect.wifidirectconnectionlistener?view=winrt-22000)  to handle incoming connection request. Is there similar APIs available for BLE?  Any suggestion/workaround is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that the code that triggers the confirmation dialog needs to run on the ASTA thread. Can you show the code that you expect to display the confirmation dialog?

Comment: You have to disable Authentication agent to prevent Windows default pairing dialog.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko, How to disable authentication agent?

Comment: Search through StackOverflow. I already posted the answer few times.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko, I did not find how to disable authentication agent. Could you share a link.?

Comment: @Sathish Reddy, not sure but probably SO removed the answer because of copyrights. Unfortunately SO does not allow any copyrights in the code so I will not share it here without copyrights.